# Has weather been weaponised?

Tags: weather, weapons, war

A [letter in The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/2012/feb/09/at-war-over-geoengineering) makes the following claims:

> While seemingly fantastical, weather has been weaponised. At least four countries – the US, Russia, China and Israel – possess the technology and organisation to regularly alter weather and geologic events for various military and black operations

...

> warfare now includes the technological ability to induce, enhance or direct cyclonic events, earthquakes, draught and flooding

**Does this technology exist?**

Comment: I remember reading about one of the first (*the* first?) uses of mustard gas during WWI where the wind suddenly turned and carried the clouds of gas back into the German ranks. Oh, you were talking about *intentional* uses of weather? :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To some extent yes.

Well know technique is [cloud seeding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) to induce rain. It was used during the Vietnam War, operation Popeye was carried out to induce heavy rains over Ho Chi Ming Trail.

> "Few aviation writers and historians seem to be aware that there were
>   three WC-130As. These three were originally trash-haulers, borrowed
>   from TAC in late 1966 for use in Operation "Popeye", the rain-making
>   mission in Southeast Asia, set to begin the following year. The intent
>   of the mission was to create enough year-round rain to keep the Ho Chi
>   Minh trails impassable with mud. Tests were conducted over Laos in
>   1966, and the operational missions began in March of 1967 from Udorn
>   RTAFB, Thailand. They were flown by crews of the 54th WRS, rotated on
>   a regular basis from Guam. In addition, 54th crews were sometimes
>   called upon to conduct synoptic weather reconnaissance from Udorn over
>   various areas of Southeast Asia, out to and including the Bay of
>   Bengal.
>
> The A-models were modified for weather reconnaissance, probably at
>   WRAMA, with the AN/AMR-1 system. They were not configured for
>   atmospheric sampling. Two were kept at Udorn, with the third rotating
>   to and from Guam for maintenance, repair, and crew changes, from June
>   1967 through late 1970. When the third one was not enroute to/from
>   Thailand, it was used for normal weather reconnaissance activities
>   from Guam. In late 1970 the A's were replaced with three 1958
>   B-models, and the rain-making mission continued through mid-1972 with
>   whichever B- or E-models were available from the 54th. After
>   re-conversion to transport, the A's were transferred to Air Force
>   Reserve units. During their brief stint as rain-makers, they flew a
>   total of 1435 "combat" sorties, and it is reported that at least one
>   of them received battle damage. All three A-models wore the standard
>   Southeast Asia camouflage colors and markings, but with no unit
>   designations of any kind. In 1973, 56-0519 was given or loaned to the
>   South Vietnamese Air Force, and it became one of the spoils of war on
>   April 30, 1975. The last reliable sighting was in April of 1999, which
>   reported her corroded and derelict at Tan Son Nhut Airport, Ho Chi
>   Minh City." [*(source)*](http://www.awra.us/gallery-jan05.htm)

Another military attempt at weather control was [Project Stormfury](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hrd_sub/sfury.html):

> Project STORMFURY was an ambitious experimental program of research on
>   hurricane modification carried out between 1962 and 1983. The proposed
>   modification technique involved artificial stimulation of convection
>   outside the eyewall through seeding with silver iodide. The
>   invigorated convection, it was argued, would compete with the original
>   eyewall, lead to reformation of the eyewall at larger radius, and
>   thus, through partial conservation of angular momentum, produce a
>   decrease in the strongest winds.

However, it not weaponizing, as it's was mainly aimed at preventing/reducing  naturally occurring hurricanes, rather than inducing them.

Answer (score 5):

The US Project HAARP ([High Frequency Active Auroral Research Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program)) powers many of the current crop of secret weather control stories: ([haarp weather control](http://www.google.com/search?q=haarp%20weather%20control&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)). Haarp [can produce artificial](http://www.livescience.com/124-artificial-neon-sky-show-created.html) aurora by heating limited parts of the ionosphere, but it's only a minor effect produced by a megawatt scale device, and the ionosphere is far removed from surface weather.
Some claim that [HAARP was used to knock out the Russian's latest mars probe](http://www.google.com/search?q=haarp%20grunt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), [however:](http://www.redorbit.com/news/space/1112441373/russia-blames-haarp-transmitter-for-phobos-grunt-failure/)

> Even if HAARP was turned on, a full-power blast would have hit the Russian probe with no more than 1.03 milliwatts of radio energy per square centimeter — about the same as pointing a 60-watt light bulb at it from 69 feet away

That's just not enough energy for HAARP to be a plausible weather control agent.
Directly back to the subject at hand: If weather's been weaponized, it's not been done through HAARP scale projects.

> **Related Question:** [Can HAARP affect weather or earthquakes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/979/can-haarp-affect-weather-or-earthquakes)

Answer (score 3):

People have attempted to weaponize lightning in some form or another at various points.

[Scientist Looks to Weaponize Ball Lightning](http://www.wired.com/dangerroom/2009/02/great-balls-of/)

> In the mid-’60s, the U.S. military started exploring ways that the
>   phenomenon might be weaponized. Take this 1965 Defense Technical
>   Information Center report on Survey of Kugelblitz Theories For
>   Electromagnetic Incendiaries, (Kugelblitz is German for ball
>   lighting). The document summarizes and evaluates the ball lightning
>   theories then prevalent, and recommends "a theoretical and
>   experimental Kugelblitz program… as a means of developing the theory
>   into a weapons application." This led to an Air Force program called Harness Cavalier, which seems to have ended without producing anything conclusive.

Wikipedia also states that an [Electrolaser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser) could be used as a weapon:

> As a weapon, to make a thunderhead deliver a precise lightning strike
>   onto a target from an aircraft; in this case, the aircraft and laser
>   can be compared to a triggered spark gap, in that the relatively minor
>   amount of initial input from the laser allows a large amount of energy
>   to flow between the cloud and the ground.

Although I don't know how likely that is.