# Has Longitudinal Wave Interferometry ever been used to alter the weather?

Tags: weather, weapons

I read about these in a few places,

[This article](http://www.prahlad.org/pub/bearden/powers_of_weapons.htm) states:

> Powers of Longitudinal Wave Interferometers
>
> 1 - influence and control the weather,
>
> 2 - deviate the giant jetstreams of the upper atmosphere,
>
> cited by Tom Bearden at Cheniere.Org

[This article](https://chemtrailsnorthnz.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/lt-col-tom-bearden-talks-about-scalar-weather-modification-technology-and-more/) states:

> The talk was given in the mid-1980s and since then, the technology has been developed into more rigorous longitudinal EM wave interferometry, which is the exact nature of those earlier weather engineering weapons.

So, do these weapons actually exist? (or are they just theoretical)

And have they ever been used?

Comment: First link is to a page with "Time Cube" levels of crazy and the second link is to a chemtrail site.  Can you come up with any better sources than that?

Comment: Googling "Longitudinal Wave Interferometry" brings up a LOT of rubbish sites, but nothing even remotely sane/reputable.  A lot of them seem to be referencing this Tom Bearden fellow, who is also involved with free energy/perpetual motion device shenanigans.

Comment: Are they _even_ theoretical, or are they just complete myths?

Comment: Can you provide any coherent definition of "longitudinal wave interferometry"??

Comment: I'll just observe that a "-meter" is something used to produce some sort of measurement.  It is not something used to cause alterations.

Comment: A search of "Longitudinal Wave Interferometry" on Web of Science, which indexes decades' worth of scientific journals, brings up no results using that as a title or topic.

Comment: This claim's confusing.  ["_Interferometry_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry) is, by definition, an observational technique.  Even if an interferometer were repurposed to perform some other task, e.g. control the weather, it'd no longer be "_interferometry_".

Comment: While not being about these specific claims https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/has-weather-been-weaponised?noredirect=1&lq=1 says some reasonably similar things exist.

Comment: @DenisStallings: The notability references in questions are allowed to be fringe - that's rather the point of the site. The real issue is (a) whether they are notable, and this seems rather borderline to me, and (b) whether they can be used to work out what the claim actually is. Anyone read/listened long enough to be able to extract that?

Comment: if anyone can summarize these comments to say something along the lines of "this is most likely pseudoscience rubbish" i would accept that as an answer

Comment: @Jimmery The "woodpecker transmitters" that the page is talking about is the soviet [Duga over-the-horizon radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duga_radar). There is nothing magical about them, they are just large radars. Look through the rest of the page, and the **amazing** claims that are being made. If that page is to be believed, those radars are so capable that not even a fictional cartoon supervillan would trust that sales pitch. "Claims without evidence can be dismissed without evidence. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence". That page has not even ordinary evidence.

Comment: @Jimmery All you have to do to answer anyone leaning on that page as "evidence" is to say "Sorry, I do not trust bad science fiction". If they say "But it is not science fiction!" just reply "Prove it...".

Comment: @Oddthinking you put it much more eloquently than me but that was kind of what I was trying to get at.  Maybe I was too quick to judge the Chemtrails site for lacking notability since they're probably all on board with this theory, but link 1 is just piles of crazy once you start exploring

Comment: Also, "Maybe I was too quick to judge the Chemtrails site for lacking notability" is a sentence I never thought I would type in my life.

Comment: @DenisStallings - Actually, here are some pictures of Soviet planes generating chemtrails: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/47997

Comment: "Telemetry" is used to send remote signals to a device, causing alterations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe "longitudinal wave interferometry" is actually a thing. Therefore, I think it's safe to say that any related weapons do not actually exist, and even implying that said weapons are "just theoretical" would be giving the whole notion too much legitimacy.

Google Scholar returns only one result for "longitudinal wave interferometry", which is a paper by Bearden and others describing an inherently-fictional free energy device.

- [Electromagnetic Energy from the Vacuum: System Efficiency (ε) and Coefficient of Performance (COP) of Symmetric and Asymmetric Maxwellian Systems](http://www.cheniere.org/techpapers/COPvsEFF23.pdf)

Regarding the second quote in your question, EM waves are transverse waves, so the mention of longitudinal EM wave interferometry doesn't even seem meaningful.

- Physics SE: [Why no longitudinal electromagnetic waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/why-no-longitudinal-electromagnetic-waves)

Lastly, interferometry is an observation and measurement technique, as many have pointed out in the comments. To say that interferometry has been used as any kind of weapon is absurd.

Comment: So basically they even got every word wrong in the name of their fictional device.  Classic.