# Are American media controlled mostly by Jews? (2015 edition)

Tags: united-states, media, jews

There is a question on this site, [Are American media controlled mostly by Jews?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/are-american-media-controlled-mostly-by-jews), which looks at an infographic titled "Who Controls Your Mind? 2013" and shows:

> The methodology of the supposed table is wrong.
>
> The table cherry picks its data points.
>
> The table has factual errors.

The infographic has been updated in the meantime. There are some 2015 versions.

Here is [one illegible version I found](https://i.redditmedia.com/3akTxcSUZpBFCQ1jUd0FxAdpNwnS46HizuqGC6xVwUg.jpg?w=1024&s=ec3ba85e06e1c04438a922328c3a0979).

Here is [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jqaY.png) via [reddit's r/conspiracy](https://www.reddit.com/r/conspiracy/comments/2v40wa/).

Does this latest version contain factual errors?

Comment: This image is illegible. Where did you find it?

Comment: A [meta-question was raised](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-we-open-another-round-of-fact-checking-on-an-updated-version-of-an-infogr) to discuss the disposition of this question.